# Pandas(or numpy) has problem for use. RuntimeError but I have installation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I already install pandas using pip.
But I can't use pandas.

For example my code just 'import pandas', and it is error :

```
RuntimeError
The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html
  File "F:\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
```

What can I do for this problem?

- Cpu : Ryzen5 4500U
- OS : Windows10 Home version 2004

Comment: Please take a look at the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) provided in the error message.

Comment: Essentially you have two options: don't use windows v2004 or build/install numpy against another BLAS library.